# How to use RedirectToAction while passing view model to a view with different route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, post-redirect-get

I have a ASP.NET MVC 3 app with a common scenario where there is  with an "`About`" controller using "`Contact`" and "`ThankYou`" actions.
I want user to go to `/about/contact`, fill out the form, submit it, and be taken to `/about/contact/thankyou` * page where the form contents (aka view model) will be displayed.

** Note there is no "Contact" controller nor do I want to create one for this purpose if possible.*

I am using `RedirectToAction` to prevent resubmission ([Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern) and `TempData` to pass on view model to thank you page.
I can also use `TempData` to check if thank you page was reached directly and redirect back to contact form page (so it would not register as a "goal" in web analytics)

But one thing I could not figure out is how to use different route for thank you page so it appears as `/about/contact/thankyou`

Am I doing this right? 
Is there a better way?

Here are relevant actions in `AboutController`

```
<!-- language: c# -->
[RequireHttps]
public ActionResult Contact()
{
    var viewModel = new ContactViewModel();
    return View(viewModel);
}
[RequireHttps]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Contact(ContactViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(viewModel);
    }       
    // not sure if this is the best way or how to redirect to /contact/thankyou 
    TempData["viewModel"] = viewModel;
    return RedirectToAction("ThankYou");
}               

[RequireHttps]
public ActionResult ThankYou()
{
    var viewModel = TempData["viewModel"];
    // upon direct access, viewModel will be null and missing, so redirect to Contact form
    if (viewModel == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Contact");
    }
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a custom route before the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "contact",
    "about/contact/thankyou",
    new { controller = "About", action = "ThankYou" }
);
```

Now when you navigate to `/about/contact` the `Contact` GET action will be executed (You have to rename it as in your code it is called `ContactUs`). Then the user fills the form and submits to the `Contact` POST action. The url stays the same for the moment: `/about/contact`. After the redirect the ThankYou action is executed and the url changes to `/about/contact/thankyou`.

Comment: this is making all of the links on the site that point to `/about/contact` be rewritten to `/about/contact/contact`...I made an edit to the code sample to rename ContactUs to Contact action...

Comment: I modified your approach and made it work. The route should be `about/contact/thankyou` and the last line should say `new { controller = "About", action = "ThankYou" }` I think you deserve the credit for giving me the idea but can you update the answer so I can mark it?